# Have a Mac mini hooked up to two screens, but can't rotate one, only both of them

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini, screen, dual-screen

Having a little problem with my Mac mini. I have two monitors set up with it, and they are working fine as a dual monitor setup. However I want to rotate one so it is in portrait mode but when I change one it alters both of them. The screens aren't being mirrored so I am a little stuck on whats happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you move the display position or change the resolution it should force a dialogue on the second monitor . . change that

Comment: Go to system preferences -> mission control. Is “use separate spaces” checked? If not, check it, log out and log back in and see if you still have that problem

Comment: Another problem might be limitations on the GPU, it can only produce limited widths and heights, and it is possible that when rotated, either one is at it’s limit.

Answer (score -1):

Connect only one display(the one to rotate) rotate it as desired then connect the other ! takes me time to figure that as well !!!